Использование цикла for в списках. Python
Мне нужен цикл for для того чтобы перебирать каждый индекс с использованием .get, обращаюсь к листу в методе класса
new_list = []

class Twolist():
     def __init__(self):
        self.new_list = new_list
 
     def create_sopr(self):
        entry31 = Text(frame2, width =22, height 
        = 6,wrap=WORD, relief=FLAT)
        entry31.tag_configure("center", 
        justify='center')
        entry31.insert("1.0", " ")
        entry31.tag_add("center", 1.0, "end")
        entry31.pack()
        frame2.create_window((self.x_pos + 150,  
        self.y_pos), window=entry31 )
        frame2.create_text(self.x_pos + 85,  
        text_y, anchor=NW, text= "Информация о \n 
        наряде сопровождения",justify="center")
        self.new_list.append (entry31)
        self.entry31 = entry31

a = new_list [for i " Не знаю что указать " [Срез равных количеству индексов в листе]].get("1.0" END) 
print(a)

Мне нужно чтобы программа работала примерно так:
print(new_list[1].get("1.0", END),
new_list[2].get("1.0", END),
new_list[3].get("1.0", END))

и тп в зависимости от количества индексов в списке.

Через .get обращаются к словарю. Приведите пример вашей структуры данных. Сейчас вообще ничего непонятно: какие у вас данные и что вы с ними хотите сделать.

Тип данных str и int

Вы хелп по циклу for читали? Но пока непонятно, действительно ли вам цикл нужен.

Читал... Вот мне тоже непонятно, нужен ли он здесь, хочу сказать только то что метод create_sopr, нужен чтобы создавать несколько текстовых полей, которые я заношу в список, и чтобы выдать все значения текста из списка я хотел сделать подставку через цикл, может есть какие-то еще варианты чтобы добиться этого?

Если я что-то понял из вашего объяснения, то списковое включение должно выглядеть примерно так:
a = [i.get("1.0", END) for i in new_list]
print(a)

По сути это как если через обычный цикл написать так:
a = []
for i in new_list:
    a.append(i.get("1.0", END))
print(a)

Убрать лишний перевод строки\n в конце строки можно через использование метода .strip:
i.get("1.0", END).strip()


Благодарю, а как избавится от ['\n'], вывод примерно следующий
['Привет\n', ' Пока\n']

Не совсем то что я хотел, хотелось бы избавиться ото всех символов и получить вместо
['Привет\n', ' Пока\n'] >>
Привет, Пока

@ТупаяНочь в этом вам поможет строковый метод strip либо же replace

strip не убирает след от списков, получается так ['Привет', 'Пока'], хотелось бы просто Привет, Пока

Господи, ну тогда print(', '.join(a))

@CrazyElf, у меня похожие эмоции, лол) Но мне было лень писать ответ на аналогичный вопрос , но не лень (до какого-то момента) попытаться объяснить, что и как сделать) (см. комменты перенесенные в чат)
